# Cannot target a specific div to populate data from jQuery AJAX ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So I have the following Javascript. I will try and figure out why the text specified inside the CommentItem div I am appending isn't showing.. But my main issue is targetting ContainerPh the one thats above the txtComment that initiated everything...

```
   $('.txtComment').live("keypress", function (event) {
$_this = $(this);

var Id = $(this).attr("index");
var d = JSON.stringify({ "Value": $(this).val(), "StreamId": Id })
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if (keycode == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../API/Services.asmx/PostComment',
        data: d,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: PostOk,
        error: errFunc
    });
    $('.txtComment').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
}

});

function PostOk(result, userContext, methodName) {

var CommentsPh = $_this.parent().parent().find(".CommentsPh");
 var CommentItem =
    "<div class='CommentItem'>" +
        "<div id='CommentImgContainer'>" +
        "<img src='' class='CommentImg'  + '.thumb' />"   
        "</div>" +
        "<div id='CommentStory'>" +
            "<a href='' class='BuddyTag small'></a>" +
            "<span class='CommentValue'>" + result.d[1] + "</span>" +
            "<br />" +
            "<div class='spacer'></div>" +
            "<span class='DateTime'>datetime</span>"
            "<span style='float: right; margin-right: 7px; margin-left:8px; line-height:8pt;'>.</span>" +
            "<span class='CommentUp'>sometext</span>" +
            "<span class='CommentLike'></span>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>";

    $(CommentsPh).append(CommentItem);

$('.txtComment').each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

This is populating all .CommentsPh even tho I am trying to get the one right before the txtComment Textbox. What am I doing wrong?

```
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteStream" CssClass="DisposeOfStream" OnClick="btnDeleteStream_Click"
                                    runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>





                                <div class="CommentsPh">
                                </div>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteStream" CssClass="DisposeOfStream" OnClick="btnDeleteStream_Click"
                                    runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel ID="CommentTools" CssClass="CommentTools" runat="server">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="txtComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't see much of the markup, so it's hard to tell that two parents above that TextBox there are not multiple .CommensPh divs (which #find would match against).

As an alternative, is there any reason to not put an id= attribute on the desired div tag, using some convention that ties the TextBox to that div?  I'm thinking something like...

```
<div id='comments_txtComment'></div>
```

... where the TextBox in question is...

```
<asp:TextBox ID='txtComment'>
```

...and then in PostOK, do something like var CommentsPh = $('comments_'+$_this.attr('id'));

Comment: I can't comment in the other responses, so I'll do it here...they keep saying that $_this variable is declared inside that keypress handler. That is not the case....it's only being assigned inside it. We don't see enough of his code to know where it's defined.  And in any case, if you don't declare vars with 'var', I believe they're global.

Comment: mmm varable scope problem is ok as you said , but you can not use like this var CommentsPh = $_this.parent().parent().find(".CommentsPh") . because you are uing an object $_this . you have to use an attribute like i said

Answer (score 1):

you can not use like

```
var CommentsPh = $_this.parent().parent().find(".CommentsPh");
```

because you specify as

```
$_this = $(this);

 $_this shoul be id or class or other attribute but not the object
```

you can use like

```
$_this = this.id;
var CommentsPh = $('#'+$_this).parent().parent().find(".CommentsPh");
```

an also the variable scope is incorrect

```
 $_this is defined in side 

$('.txtComment').live("keypress", function (event) {
```

so it can use in only that function

declare it out side any function but inside

```
$(document).ready
```

like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $_this = '';

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `Id tag` to your `div` whom you want to find in DOM.
then search.

```
<div id="comment" class="CommentsPh">
                                    hhvghg
                                </div>
```

then search according to their ID tag either its ID changes.Use this code snippet to find the DIV

```
$('div[id*=comment]').hide();
```